# CentOS7/GDM/Xfce - Locale set to xxx.UTF-8 at session start despite system-wide locale to xxx.iso88591

Tags: centos, xfce, locale, gdm, i18n

I'm using CentOS 7 with XFCE and GDM.

My issue is as follows: I want my locale to be **LANG=fr_FR.iso88591** (required by an antic piece of software).

Following CentOS official guide, I did the following:

```
$ localectl list-locales | grep fr_FR
fr_FR
fr_FR.iso88591
fr_FR.iso885915@euro
fr_FR.utf8
fr_FR@euro
$ sudo localectl set-locale LANG=fr_FR.iso88591
```

I can check this actually worked:

```
$ cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG=fr_FR.iso88591
$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.iso88591
       VC Keymap: fr
      X11 Layout: fr
       X11 Model: pc105
     X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

However, after reboot(s), this happens:

```
$ echo $LANG
fr_FR.UTF-8
```

It looks like gdm or Xfce are resetting the locale to UTF-8. But having grepped all my `~/.*` files for `UTF` string, I cannot find where this happens and it drives me mad!

Would you happen to know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that gdm saves the LANG variable for `<user_name>` in the file:

```
/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<user_name>
```

One just needs to change the LANG setting there, log out and then back in!

More info here: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/session-user.html.en